# how to download files from url and store in document folder

Tags: ios, objective-c, download

I created one application that has two page (first page for show list of data and second page for show detail data).

when click on any cell go to next page and in next page exists one button with name : DOWNLOAD
that I want when I click on that button this file download and save in document folder.
I dont know about it. please guide me that how download any file and store in document folder.
I searching in internet but I dont understand about it.

please tell me with code that how downloaded any file with one button. Im sorry if I not good english.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

It is this simple my friend,

```
NSString *stringURL = @"http://www.somewhere.com/thefile.png";
NSURL  *url = [NSURL URLWithString:stringURL];
NSData *urlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
if ( urlData )
{
  NSArray       *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
  NSString  *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];  

  NSString  *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", documentsDirectory,@"filename.png"];
  [urlData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
}
```

*it advisable to execute the code in a separate thread.*

EDIT 1: more info

1) for large file downloads,

```
-(IBAction) downloadButtonPressed:(id)sender;{
    //download the file in a seperate thread.
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        NSLog(@"Downloading Started");
        NSString *urlToDownload = @"http://www.somewhere.com/thefile.png";
        NSURL  *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlToDownload];
        NSData *urlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
        if ( urlData )
        {
            NSArray       *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
            NSString  *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

            NSString  *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", documentsDirectory,@"filename.png"];

            //saving is done on main thread
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [urlData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
                NSLog(@"File Saved !");
            });
        }

    });

}
```

Comment: my friend I want save with self name . what I do?

Comment: What do you mean by self name ? What is the file URL of the file you are going to download, any example ?

Comment: my friend I want when to click button run specific url and download file in it.

Comment: my friend work it....if I want download file with large size this way is work???

Comment: Now you should be clear on everything. I added more info to my answer.

Comment: work it but if I want download file with large size this way work it?

Comment: for large file downloads, I updated my answer..

Comment: thank you my friend I have last question I want to use UIProgress View for show download but I dont know about please guide me?

Comment: If you use, AFNetworking framework there are simple methods you can use like this, downloadoperation setDownloadProgressBlock:^(NSUInteger bytesRead, long long totalBytesRead, long long totalBytesExpectedToRead) {
        float progress = ((float)totalBytesRead) / totalBytesExpectedToRead;
        self.progressView.progress = progress;
    }]; ...........  Spend some time on https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking, really worth

Comment: Can you also tell how to play a video file from Documents directory into our app ?

Comment: hello @ThilinaChaminHewagama your answer is very nice detailed. could you have a look at this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36018080/download-all-available-and-new-files/36018253

Comment: Thanks but How do i get a callback when the download is over?

Comment: @HaraHaraMahadevaki, at "NSLog(@"File Saved !");" you know the download is over. you can call any method there.

Comment: Haha You say it's simple but saved my day. Mega kudos to the author.