# On iOS, is `Application Support` directory safe to keep large data?

Tags: ios

My app needs to download about 200MB files and use them in the future. I tried to place them into the `Cache` and `Temp` directories but both of them may be killed when the iOS found disk capacity is getting low.

I don't want my files to be killed randomly so I'm asking:

If the `Application Support` directories would be OK, no unexpected killing, for my files?

Will the `Application Support` be removed when the app uninstalled?

Comment: It would be better to store in cache/temp files and let the system remove when/if required then you just download. You don't want to be clogging up memory with large files of data, especially in application support. Though there is nothing wrong with storing in there as far as I know. However have you considered the Documents Directory? This would be the better solution if you don't want to store in cache.

Comment: I can't use Documents because Apple will reject my app if I use to much space in Documents. I need always keep my download files. The files are not temporary the app always need them.

Comment: Sorry but your out of luck then. The Documents directory is for this sort of thing so if your files are to big for that folder it will certainly be to big for the Application Support folder. You're going to have to review your requirements and consider what else you can do.

Comment: @jayatubi http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16392420/how-to-download-files-from-url-and-store-in-document-folder
Refer that for downloading and accessing file