# Download all available (and new) files

Tags: ios, objective-c, download, nsurlsessiondownloadtask

I'm using `NSURLSessionDownloadTask` to download some **.mov** files from a web and storing them in my app.

Now what I'd like to achieve is to

- download **ALL** files of certain type (in this case .mov) available on the page, without having to specify every file URL
- download files **ONLY** if they are not already stored in my app.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

1. You would have to scrape that html page to get all the urls (.mov) you are looking for. Either you can use `NSXMLParser` if you want to write your own or you can google some library.
2. When you download a file, persist some metadata (eg. name or some unique identifier) either in SQLite or CoreData, so that you can check if the file has already been downloaded.

Comment: well yes, this is the idea. I was asking if someone could help achieving it

Comment: [Nice tutorial to parse html](https://www.raywenderlich.com/14172/how-to-parse-html-on-ios). I would start with this. Then to persist data I would [Read this](https://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-tutorial-for-ios-getting-started). Let me know if you need some other help.