# UIDocumentInteractionController to open with URL from web without saving in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uidocumentinteraction, open-with

I need to open a file from web url and open in other apps that have installed in the device using UIDocumentInteractionController

var controller:UIDocumentInteractionController?

```
self.controller? = UIDocumentInteractionController.init(URL: (NSURL(string: self.filesUrl))!)
```

where  `self.filesUrl = self.filesDetailArrayResponse.valueForKey("url")` as! `NSArray` is from the json response

But `self.controller` returning nil value

Comment: can you tell me which file are you trying to open in `UIDocumentInteractionController` ?

Comment: @Dhanesh The files of types like image files(.jpeg,.png), video(.mp4) and text file (.txt) which is stored in server and should be opened directly with other apps installed in device but should not  save those files in local device and should be opened directly with other apps installed in the device..

Comment: Did you find a solution for this please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not possible do it with web URL, the file must be in the local filesystem as a file URL. From the [apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidocumentinteractioncontroller/1616804-url):

> UIDocumentInteractionController
>
> var url: URL? { get set }
>
> The URL identifying the target file **on the local filesystem**.

So how to solve it, download the file, the write it in the local filesystem and then give the local URL to the `UIDocumentInteractionController` (for example with: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16392475/1791179)